# how compiler differentiates between private and public data in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

For example,

```
Class Test {
        private:
            int x;
        public:
            int y;
}obj;
```

Now, obj.y can be accessed but not obj.x

My question is how compiler restricts access to private data?

Besides, how can I implement access specifiers in C structures?

Comment: It is only a compile time thing. There is no special memory management going on. The compiler just stops with an error if your code tries to access that value in a way it is not allowed.

Comment: Does the last question refer to C, or to a `struct` in C++? In C, you can't; in C++, you can use specifiers in a `struct` just like a `class`. The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that `struct` makes things public by default.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler have all information about all the code in a *translation unit* (a source file and all included header files), and can therefore keep track of which members are private and which are not. *How* the compiler does it is not relevant, and different compilers can implement it differently.

Private/public members is a pure compile-time concept, and there is nothing in the compiled executable code that enforces it.

Comment: That's right. Suppose I have to implement the concept of access specifiers in C structures. How this can be achieved.

Comment: @vishal: if you mean that you are writing a C program and you want to use access specifiers, then you can't. If you mean that you are writing a C compiler and you want it to offer access specifiers as a non-standard extension to the C language then (a) it's a lot of work, and (b) first you'll have to define what you mean, because C doesn't have classes and so the public/private distinction doesn't translate directly from C++. If by "C structure" you just mean a C++ class defined with the `struct` keyword, then you use them the same as in a class defined with the `class` keyword.

Comment: @SteveJessop, suppose c++ doesn't exist, and you are implementing this feature for a new OO language.

Comment: @vishal then you write a compiler and you make it check access. The question hardly even makes sense. If writing a new compiler for a new language then you make the compiler enforce the rules of the language.  _How_ you do it depends on the details of your new compiler, which is hypothetical and pointless to speculate on.

Comment: @vishal: then in your compiler, you will have some data stored regarding each data member of the class: its name, type, position in the class data, etc. As part of this data, store the data member's access. When you are resolving code that uses the data member, compare the member's access against the location of the calling code (in the same class; in a friend of the class; in a derived class; other). Reject the code if the location is not suitable for the access.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how compiler restricts access to private data?

When the source code refers to any variable a C++ compiler has to do name lookup to find the variable (it could be a local variable, a member variable, a global variable etc.) and it has to do access checking. The compiler has all the information about the types, variables and scopes, so when the source code refers to a variable the compiler knows if the variable is accessible.  If the variable isn't accessible the compiler rejects the source code.

Asking "how" doesn't really have an sensible answer - it's the compiler, that's what it does.  Knowing how it does it is no help to you if you're trying to write C code to do the same, because what you can do in a program's source code is entirely different to what a compiler does.  It's like asking how an aeroplane flies, then asking how you can fly in a car. Knowing the answer to one is irrelevant to the other.

> Besides, how can I implement access specifiers in C structures?

Two options:

1. C doesn't support that, use C++
2. store a `void*` in the struct which points to some opaque type, and only have "private" functions (i.e. internals to the API) know the details of that opaque type.

Here's a quick example

```
//
// in header only "public" data is visible
//

struct Data {
    int some_number;
    void* private_data;
};

Data* create_Data(int i, int j);
void manipulate_Data(Data*);

//
// in source file, these functions know what the `void*` points to and can use it
//

struct InternalData {
    int another_number;
};

InternalData* get_internals(Data* d)
{
    return (InternalData*)d->private_data;
}

Data* create_Data(int i, int j)
{
    Data* data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    data->some_number = i;
    InternalData* internal = (InternalData*)malloc(sizeof(InternalData));
    internal->another_number = j;
    data->private_data = internal;
}

void manipulate_Data(Data* d)
{
    data->some_number += get_internals(d)->another_number;
}
```

Comment: Using PIMPL, you have achieved it right. But the size of a c++ class (atleast in GCC) is the sum of the sizes of its data members. So, GCC couldn't be using this option to implement access specifiers.

Comment: No, of course not, I never claimed that. In C++ you don't need to do that, because the language supports it directly. In C the language doesn't support it, so you have to do it differently. If you want the features of C++  **then use C++!**.  You **cannot** "implement access specifiers" in source code, it's built in to the language!

Comment: It's a question out of curiosity that may not have any realistic need, when C++ provides the functionality. The simple question is how gcc or the language supports it?

Comment: It's not a simple question. How does GCC support functions? How does it support `const`? How does it support addition of numbers?  It's a C++ compiler, it implementes the language, by parsing the source code and checking that it is valid according to the rules of the language. To answer the question properly you'll have to read hundreds of lines of source code in GCC, so if you're really curious then do that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of reading the source code. If I find something useful I will let you know.